# How to do double domain crosshair using jFreeChart

Tags: java, android, charts, jfreechart, android-animation

How can I implement the double domain cross-hairs for my jfreechart? Here is the requirement I need to honor.

[image]

The image is photo edited to show my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ValueMarker`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ValueMarker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461149/230513). You'll need to set the *dash attributes* in your [`Stroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html); [`DEFAULT_GRIDLINE_STROKE`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#line.318) is an example.

Comment: But my requirement needs both the cross-hairs to be movable dynamically firing crosshairs co-ordinates to update my below table.

Comment: You can implement [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html), as illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8525187/230513).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me try it.