# JfreeChart and ValueMarker not displayed (headless environment)

Tags: jfreechart, redhat, marker, headless

I have a problem while generating a chart. Every part on the chart is well generated except a ValueMarker which is not. I am working on a web application in a headless RedHat environment. I got another problem for the chart generation (which is now solved), the description of my environment is here :

[JFreeChart strange rendering (headless RedHat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762928/jfreechart-strange-rendering-headless-redhat)

It is working perfectly on Windows.
The piece of code adding the ValueMarker is :

```
Marker distanceTiers = new ValueMarker(Double.parseDouble(resultDistance.replace(Constants.UNITE_DISTANCE, "")));
distanceTiers.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
plot.addDomainMarker(distanceTiers);
```

Here is what I obtain, I am supposed to get a vertical line at X = 40 and I cannot figure out why everything except this line is going well :

[image: http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/6050/graph20120803141353.png]

If someone has an explanation for this, please do not hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you get the domain value used to construct the `ValueMarker`, but you might compare your approach to that shown in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4407735/230513)

Comment: In this example, the value is 40. It is working fine on windows, but not on my linux machine. The cause was that the stroke was not specified in my code. After specifying it, it is ok.